# How to Format epoch in js with minimal code?

Tags: javascript, php

This is done in php...

```
$time = "1512486297"
$formated_time = date("F d, Y h:i:s A", $time);//December 05, 2017 03:04:57 PM
```

Now How do i do this in js
Here is my code

```
success: function(response){
 var date = response.date;  // date in  Unix timestamp
}
```

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: https://makitweb.com/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-time-with-javascript/

Comment: @rprakash - Problem solved . if there is any shortcut let me know.Thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/